# Display InfoWindow for KML when placing marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display an infowindow (showing KML description of polygon) when a marker is placed after geocoding an address.  I have everything working except for the infowindow. I currently have it to display "Hello World", but I'm wondering if there is a way to call the "description" info from the polygon that the marker is located in.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAd0xb3vfvpGxZphXuVQ8UVWsACtitEd64&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function detectBrowser() {
        var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
        var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

        if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
            mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
            mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
        } else {
            mapdiv.style.width = '600px';
            mapdiv.style.height = '800px';
        }}

      function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.59704151614417, -85.77713012695312); 
        var mapOptions = {
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false,
            center: latlng,
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
        };

    var styleArray  = [
      {
        featureType: "landscape",
        stylers: [
          { hue: "#ffbb00" },
          { saturation: -23 },
          { lightness: 2 }
        ]
      },{
        featureType: "poi",
        stylers: [
          { hue: "#ff0055" },
          { saturation: -31 }
        ]
      },{
        featureType: "road",
        stylers: [
          { hue: "#0033ff" },
          { saturation: -42 },
          { lightness: 11 },
          { weight: 0.9 }
        ]
      },{
        featureType: "water",
        stylers: [
          { hue: "#003bff" },
          { lightness: 12 },
          { saturation: 25 }
        ]
      },{
      }
    ];

    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styleArray,
    {name: "Styled Map"});

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.farmerstel.com/map/FTCFIBER.kml',{
                      map: map,
                      preserveViewport: true
                  });
        nyLayer.setMap(map);

        map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
        map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

      }

    var geocoder;
    var map;

    // Check for geolocation support
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // Use method getCurrentPosition to get coordinates
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        // Access them accordingly
        map.setCenter(34.496937, -85.839958);
    });
    }

    function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address, 'bounds': bounds}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location),
        map.setZoom(15);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map:map,
            draggable:false,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        // Creating an InfoWindow object
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Hello World'
        });
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
    }

    </script>
    </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div>
        <input id="address" type="textbox" size="80" value="144 McCurdy Ave North">
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:95%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently there isn't any way to do that using KmlLayer (you only get infowindows if you click on the map).

There are two options:

1. Use a third party parser like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) to parse and display the kml in the client, then you can keep references to the individual objects and trigger clicks on them externally.  Not a good choice if you have lots of placemarks or complex kml.

[example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html)

1. Import your kml into FusionTables and use FusionTablesLayer to display it, then query the table for the information to put in the infowindow

[example using FusionTablesLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_collection-map2e_FT.html)

Comment: Thank you. I had previously looked at the example at http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/votemap_sidebar.html and found what it done when geocoding an address to be perfect, but I've been trying to find the source code for it, since I'm not a programmer and struggle to accomplish basic things. Do you know of a location of the source for that "votemap sidebar" example or the first example that you shown me?

Comment: Most browsers have a view source functionality that lets you see the HTML source.  The code for all my examples is inline with the HTML (except for external javascript libraries/utilities).  In modern browsers you can usually find the view source under tools, in the version of Firefox I am currently using,it is Tools:Web developer:Page Source.

Comment: Duh! I didn't think about it being viewable in the source.  I don't know what I was thinking. I have tried copying your source and simply replacing the source of the KML to get it to load, but no polygons are showing up. Can you tell me what I've done wrong? *edit* I guess it would help if I shown what I had so far. http://farmerstel.com/map/map.html

Comment: I see polygons and [it](http://farmerstel.com/map/map.html) seems to sort of work (if I geocode an address and click on a polygon, I get two infowindows, I don't like that, but it may be what you want).

Comment: Sorry I didn't get to post last night. I figured out that the extension of the file has to be XML instead of KML. Thank you so much for your help.  I don't like the two infowindows either, but that was how it worked on the example and I tried to stop that from happening, but nothing I tried worked.

Comment: Fixed the [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html) to have a single infowindow.

Comment: Fixed both examples.  There is an "infoWindow" option that allows the reference to the infowindow that is used by the geocoder to be passed into geoxml3 so it can use it as well.  That was added and it looks like those examples hadn't been updated.

Comment: Tried which one?  What did you do to make the 2 infowindows appear?  It is certainly possible I missed something.

Comment: I tried it on both.  I simply searched a location, then clicked on a boundary to get both to show up.

Comment: What would be the best way to cache the point and address that are geocoded?  I was thinking about adding to the geocoder.geocode function to INSERT INTO a row into a Fusion Table.  I'm not sure if this would work or if it would be the best method to do such.